# Why is my JSON response not showing up as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have two forms on the page. Ditto. Same. But on one it shows good on the other one. It wont show anything in the right place, rather just a raw JSON output.

```
{"isSuccessful":false,"message":"
The Username field is required<\/p>\n
The Password field is required<\/p>\n"}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect us to do without seeing your code?  Please be sure to post all relevant code; otherwise, our guess is as good as yours :)

Comment: That newline after message looks incorrect. #guess

Comment: Okey now what happens is that I fixed something but the json response of the form on the RIGHT appears on the LEFT's. Why is that . I have all IDs changed

Comment: @JoeTuskan: Check oout the attached snap.

Answer (score 0):

If that's actually how the JSON is formatted, it isn't valid JSON. It would need to be

```
{"isSuccessful":false,"message":"The Username field is required<\/p>\nThe Password field is required<\/p>\n"}
```

(note how it is on one line - check it at http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: It was on 1 line I pressed tab here to make it on 3.